# How can I pass an app script function value (a string) to a google sheet cell as an importXML function directly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have many urls I want to pull some info from with importxml on a [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wdV1idApNKVUv1iS0nuWMDxPJDnJrNut5J6fzOV6gb4/edit#gid=156581341).
I'm trying to get review scores of monitors from a website.

I want to create a function so that when I give it a cell as reference (that contains a product's url) it will create a string for an importxml function (with a fixed and proper xpath) and pass it to the cell it is called. (or an adjacent one)

```
function puan(x) {
  var cellFunction = '=IMPORTXML("' + x + '";"//div[@id=\'puan\']//@data-percent")';
  return cellFunction;
}
```

I tried something like this but it didn't work. It just returns the value like a string.
The string looks ok and it returns the value I want if it is directly passed to the cell.

Then I tried this to select the active cell and pass the value there but it didn't work.
I think I'm using it wrong. In the documentation of app script it says custom funcions can only change the value of the cell it is called (or adjacent ones)

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().setValue(cellFunction);
```

When I add this to my function and delete "return cellFunction;" it returns "0"
I think I'm using it wrong.

Can you guide me because I couldn't find a solution?
I'm also open to suggestions for better ways of extracting same info.

Comment: You should use a menu or a button

Answer (score 0):

You should be using setFormula() for this purpose: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula

If you still can't get it to work, share a copy of your sheet and I will try to help further.

Comment: I already shared the sheet linked to "google sheet" but also here it is
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wdV1idApNKVUv1iS0nuWMDxPJDnJrNut5J6fzOV6gb4/edit#gid=156581341

Thanks for the answer btw I'll try to solve it with your advice. (but I'm not much experienced with google sheets etc.)

Answer (score 0):

### You have two options:

- **Either return `cellFunction` to the main function by calling `puan(x)` inside the main function**

Sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var URL = "Your URL" 
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().setValue(puan(URL));
}


function puan(x) {
  var cellFunction = '=IMPORTXML("' + x + '";"//div[@id=\'puan\']//@data-percent")';
  return cellFunction;
}
```

- **Or set the value into the spreadsheet inside `puan(x)`**

Sample:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var URL = "Your URL"
  puan(URL);
}

function puan(x) {
 var cellFunction = '=IMPORTXML("' + x + '";"//div[@id=\'puan\']//@data-percent")'; 
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().setValue(cellFunction);
}
```

Note:

Using `setFormula()` instead of `setValue()` is in your case possible, but optional.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, OP is using `=puan(x)` in a cell. Puan is a custom function.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now, thanks for clarification @TheMaster.

Comment: Well, unfortunately @Timobonus a custom function cannot return a function into a cell - otherwise it would overwrite itself. What you can do is create a button to which you assign one of the scripts proposed and then run your function [on button click](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets) or run the script from the [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#custom_menus_in_google_docs_sheets_slides_or_forms).

Comment: If it is important for you to use a custom function isntead of a button click - consider using the Apps Script [XML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service) to parse data and return to the spreadsheet, but this is more complicated and probably an overkill for your purpose.